# Linking different screens in React Native

Tags: react-native, screen, react-native-navigation

I wanted to open different screen if pressed the text. But unfortunately I don't understand this [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation). Is there any other different option, like 'a href' in html? Or could anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install react-navigation
2. Make edits to `App.js`

   - Wrap all of the JSX of App.js in a NavigationContainer with a Stack.Navigator nested under it

   ```js
     import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
     import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

     const Stack = createStackNavigator();

     return (
       <NavigationContainer>
         <Stack.Navigator>
          {Your Screens}
         </Stack.Navigator>
       </NavigationContainer>
   );
   ```
3. Now we set up screens. Each screen will use the StackScreen component and needs a screen name and the screen component itself

```js
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsScreen}
      />
```

4. With this completed, each screen will now have a navigation prop. In the screen where you have your text button set your onPress to something like this:

```js
  <Button
    title="Navigate to Home"
    onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate("Home")
  />
```

- navigation.navigate identifies the screen you're trying to get to by using the name you provided in App.js Stack.Screen

Comment: I did what you asked me to and there is an errror with <Stack.Navigator>. it says 'undefined is not an object(_reactNative.Stack.Navigator)'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the imports. I've updated the answer to include them